How to place tableHeaderView under UITableViewCell
i need to create a tableView like the one below.
Curently the yellow section on top is a tableHeaderView and everything below is a UITableViewCell.
The question is that I need to place the first UITableViewCell (that has two views with chevrons below) a bit above the tableHeaderView.
Any ideas how can I do it?


How about combining both the header and the first cell into a single header/cell?

@sonle according to the state the header may be replaced with some other view that doesn't go under the first cell. to go that direction i need to create two cells actually. that's why i didn't prefer it.

i think i need to update the frame of the first cell but somehow it doesnt get updated

You cannot update the cell frame directly, it will only work with heightForRowAt delegate or automaticDimension

@BurakAkyalçın - what are you trying to accomplish? Should the "two chevron views" scroll up (and out of view) when you scroll the table? Should your "header view" move up, push up the chevron views, but then "stick" to the top as you scroll the rest of the table up (underneath the header)? Should the two chevron views simply always be there?
